# How to get number of neurons in TensorFlow layer?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I am trying to connect the output of a pooling layer to a dense layer. In order to do this, I need to flatten the pooled tensor. Consider the layers below:

```
def conv_layer(input, in_channels, out_channels, name="conv"):
    w = tf.get_variable("W", initializer=tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, in_channels, out_channels], stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.get_variable("B", initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[out_channels]))
    conv = tf.nn.conv2d(input, w, strides=[1,1,1,1], padding="SAME")
    act = tf.nn.relu(conv + b)
    return act

def pool_layer(input, name="pool"):
    pool = tf.nn.max_pool(input, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding="SAME")
    return pool

def dense_layer(input, size_in, size_out, name="dense"):
    w = tf.get_variable("W", initializer=tf.truncated_normal([size_in, size_out], stddev=0.1))
    b = tf.get_variable("B", initializer=tf.constant(0.1, shape=[size_out]))
    act = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(input, w) + b)
    return act
```

I am using them to create a network:

```
def cnn_model(x):
    x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, nseries, present_window, 1])
    conv1 = conv_layer(x_image, 1, 32, "conv1")
    pool1 = pool_layer(conv1, "pool1")
    conv2 = conv_layer(pool1, 32, 64, "conv2")
    pool2 = pool_layer(conv2, "pool2")
    nflat = 17*15*64 # hard-coded
    flat  = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, nflat])
    yhat = dense_layer(flat, nflat, future_window, "dense1")
    return yhat
```

As you can see I am hard-coding the variable `nflat`. How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a tensor `pool.get_shape()` should work on Keras or Tensorflow.

This will actually return a tuple with the size of each dimension, so you need to choose from it, probably it's the 2nd in your case.

If input is actually your input (without any other layer), why are you max-pooling? aren't you looking for `dropout` ?

Indeed you will find a problem if your batch size is variable, since there's no way of telling the model the size of the `reshape`

Comment: I tried using `get_shape().to_list()` but it returns a list of ints and `None` as well when the dimension is the batch dimension? Is this the only way to go about it? It seems very low level.

Comment: Thank you for the update @Diego, I updated my question to include more information. Sorry I wasn't clear in my first attempt.